# jstree triggering the sort plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jstree

After having found a "feature" in jstree, I have now spent most of a day trying to find out how to trigger the sort plugin in jstree.

I am using jstree, and wanted to sort it in a style similar to filesystems, where elements with children are grouped together.
(i.e. folders / directories) and elements without children (files) are grouped together, the sort plugin will not always work as expected.

To do this I added the following to the tree construction:

```
$(jQueryIdString).jstree({
        'core': { check_callback: true },
        "plugins": ["search", "sort"],
        'sort': function (a, b) {
            var nodeA = this.get_node(a);
            var nodeB = this.get_node(b);
            var lengthA = nodeA.children.length;
            var lengthB = nodeB.children.length;                
            if ((lengthA == 0 && lengthB == 0) || (lengthA > 0 && lengthB > 0))
                return this.get_text(a).toLowerCase() > this.get_text(b).toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
            else
                return lengthA > lengthB ? -1 : 1;
        }
});
```

### But ran into trouble when I allowed the user to dynamicly add elements.

The case is that the last element you add is a "folder", but is has no children yet so it is sorted alphabetically, and then you add a "file" in that folder.
- but this does not re-sort the parent, as jstree sorting doesn't realise that children may affect parents??

to fix this without redesigning how to build the tree, I ended up using something like this code (that I am not happy about):

```
var selector = '#treeId';
var root = $(selector).jstree(true).get_node("root_anchor")
var dummyNode = $(selector).jstree(true).create_node(root, "sorting dummy node");
$(selector).jstree(true).delete_node(dummyNode);
```

I have not yet determined if you would need to do this for all children (that has children)

If anybody has found a better way to do this, I would much appreciate it.

*In case you see the API, youll notice that there is a method:*

```
.is_parent(node)
```

*that could be used instead of children.length.*

but it does not solve my problem. I started out with that, but then started to inspect the children, and found out that infact there was no children at the time of sorting..

I will not be using the types plugin, unless I have to!
This is not actually a filesystem!

**How should I have done this? **

Requirements:

1. I need to add a new child node
2. If this requires the parent to move
   from the "group" that has no children to the group that has, it
   should be sorted properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger a sort you should be able to do:

```
$(selector).jstree(true).sort(root, true);
$(selector).jstree(true).redraw_node(root, true);
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).jstree(...).sort is not a function